# SQL inicial para listar clientes (PF e PJ). Como migrar uma Query SQL pura para Eloquent do Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

Montei uma SQL inicial para puxar os dados. Está funcionando no SQL puro. Preciso de migrar este código para padrão eloquent do Laravel. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Segue a SQL de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
SELECT c.cod_cliente, p.cpf, p.nome, ct_mpf.cod_contrato_pessoa_fisica_plano, ct_mpf.numero_contrato_membro AS numero_contrato_membro_pf, pjc.cod_contrato_pessoa_juridica_plano, pjc.numero_contrato_membro AS numero_contrato_membro_pj, pj.razao_social,
(
CASE
    WHEN c.usufrui_de_um_contrato = 1 
    THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN ct_mpf.vinculo = 1 THEN 'membro' 
            WHEN ct_mpf.vinculo = 2 THEN 'rf_membro' 
            WHEN ct_mpf.vinculo = 3 THEN 'rf'
            ELSE null
        END 
    WHEN c.usufrui_de_um_contrato = 2 
    THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN pjc.vinculo = 1 THEN 'membro' 
            WHEN pjc.vinculo = 2 THEN 'submembro'
            ELSE null
        END 
END
) AS vinculo
FROM pessoa AS p
LEFT JOIN clientes AS c ON c.cod_pessoa = p.cod_pessoa
LEFT JOIN pessoa_fisica AS pf ON pf.cod_cliente = c.cod_cliente
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT ctpf.cod_pessoa_fisica AS pf_do_contrato, m.cod_pessoa_fisica AS pf_do_membro, ctpf.cod_contrato_pessoa_fisica_plano, m.numero_contrato_membro, m.vinculo
    FROM contratos_pessoa_fisica_planos AS ctpf
    INNER JOIN membros AS m
    ON ctpf.cod_contrato_pessoa_fisica_plano = m.cod_contrato_pessoa_fisica_plano
    WHERE ctpf.status = 1 AND m.status = 1
    ORDER BY ctpf.created_at DESC
) AS ct_mpf ON ct_mpf.pf_do_contrato = pf.cod_pessoa_fisica AND ct_mpf.pf_do_membro = pf.cod_pessoa_fisica
LEFT JOIN pessoa_juridica_clientes AS pjc ON pjc.cod_cliente = c.cod_cliente
LEFT JOIN pessoa_juridica AS pj ON pj.cod_pessoa_juridica = pjc.cod_pessoa_juridica
WHERE p.cpf = 12345 OR p.nome LIKE '%JOSUE%
```

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: Você já criou as Models para pessoa, clientes, pessoa_fisica, etc? Primeiro passo será criar essas models, com seus respectivos relacionamentos (Veja a documentação oficial: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) Depois você poderá fazer o tratamento que precisa em algum Controller. Existem formas mais diretas de fazer essas buscas usando Eloquent, mas se quiser, também tem a possibilidade de executar um código sql diretamente através dos "Raw Methods" (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions) Dê uma olhada nesse link também: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries Abraços!